# Create minor version from old tag in Github

Tags: github, tagging, hotfix

I have an application for which we may create a hotfix branch from old tag (which is live in production). Current TAGs can be far ahead of that, as we may not release changes too quickly.

How can I create a minor version in continuation of the old tag now? For example,

```
Production TAG - 0.20.0 [I'm creating a new branch from this]
Current Master - 0.29.0
Expected TAG - 0.20.1
Generated TAG - 0.29.1
```

I'm using https://github.com/mathieudutour/github-tag-action v6 to generate the tag.

The GH action usage looks something like below:

```
   uses: mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v6.1
   with:
    github_token: ***
    default_bump: minor
    custom_release_rules: fix:patch,feat:minor,perf:major
    dry_run: true
    release_branches: main,hotfix
    default_prerelease_bump: prerelease
    create_annotated_tag: false
    fetch_all_tags: false
```

Comment: There's no problem creating any tag from any SHA, in GIT. This is a problem with github-tag-action